# how can i log exceptions from ListCreateAPIView generic view

Tags: django, logging, django-rest-framework

this is my generic view,i want to log exceptions that occurs when invalid post request is made to this view.

```
from rest_framework.generics import (ListCreateAPIView)
class ProjectListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

your question is very generic, so here is 3 generic answer (choose one that fits more):

1. you can override DRF exception handler to and log errors there [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)
2. in your serializer class write custom `validate` [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) or `validate_<field>` [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) and log error for each field
3. in your viewset override `create`/ `perform_create` method and log errors [ListCreateAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) is based using [CreateModelMixin](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin) which provides methods for creating new objects, you need to override those methods and handle errors there
4. write a custom django middleware (it's a low level solution) [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/)

Comment: thanks aliva for help.
first one seems more suitable, but the problem is i want to log exception occured by sending null value in mandatory fields. but documentation says:
"Note that the exception handler will only be called for responses generated by raised exceptions. It will not be used for any responses returned directly by the view, such as the HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST responses that are returned by the generic views when serializer validation fails."